# Calculate number of colliding numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dataset of events for a calendar. It is going to be placed into a grid.

I am trying to count the highest numbers of events that collide at the same time. Every event has a `start` time and `end` time.

What I have done so far is count the number of matches, but this won't find the maximum of collisions..

```js
const events = [{
    id: 0,
    start: 6,
    end: 9,
    title: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    start: 6,
    end: 9,
    title: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    start: 7,
    end: 8,
    title: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    start: 10,
    end: 15,
    title: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    start: 20,
    end: 25,
    title: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    start: 21,
    end: 23,
    title: "Hello"
  },
]

// Check how many events are colliding at same time, to make more columns
let items = []
events.map(event => {
  const matches = events.filter(o => {
    //console.log(o.start, "is smaller or same", event.start, o.start <= event.end)
    return o.start <= event.end && o.end >= event.start && event.id !== o.id
  })
  items.push({
    ...event,
    matches
  })
})

const collitions = items.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.matches < b.matches) return 1
  if (a.matches > b.matches) return -1
  return 0
})[0].matches.length + 1

console.log('There is', collitions, 'collitions')
```

Here is the grid when the calculation is using the events data in the example. It outputs three, which is correct.

[image]

Here is the grid when there is an event which is the whole day. It outputs 6 colliding events, but that's wrong. It is 4 colliding events in a row.

[image]

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. do you want two groups or max three items who collide?

Comment: @NinaScholz If you think in rows, I would like to to count the amount of items in one row. In my example it is 3, but one event can be the whole day, and then get six matches, which would output a result which is wrong.

Comment: why is it wrong by having six matches?

Comment: @NinaScholz because it isn't six events in a row. In my example there is three events in a row, by adding a new event that last the whole day, it will count that it collides will all events (6). However there are only four events in a row. I am looking for the amount of events that is in a row, not how many events it collides with.

Comment: maybe you add a small graphic of the rows.

Comment: @NinaScholz Added some picture examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution.

#### Approach

- Have an array of length 24 so that each value will represent 1 hour
- Loop through the each event and increment the value at each hour for the duration
- At the end find the max value in the array

#### Code

```js
const events = [{
    id: 0,
    start: 6,
    end: 9,
    title: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    start: 6,
    end: 9,
    title: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    start: 7,
    end: 8,
    title: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    start: 10,
    end: 15,
    title: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    start: 20,
    end: 25,
    title: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    start: 21,
    end: 23,
    title: "Hello"
  },
]

const array = new Array(24).fill(0)
events.forEach(function(event) {
  for (let i = event.start; i < event.end; ++i) {
    ++array[i]
  }
})

let maxEvents = -1
for (let i = 0; i< array.length; ++i) {
  if (array[i] > maxEvents) maxEvents = array[i]
}

console.log("collisions: ", maxEvents)
console.log("collision array:", JSON.stringify(array))
```

*Have checked it for case when event.start = 0 and event.end = 23, and it is giving the correct output*

#### Note:

The solution will also work in case start and end time are `hm:mm`. In this case, we need to have array of length `24*60 (hours*mins)`. Also, `i` inside for loop will be the total number of minutes starting from 0 (e.g. `2:45 mean i = 165`).

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: Thanks for this and for taking your time. Would it maybe be possible to have the start and end times to be like HH:mm, as events time can vary? I initially chose 0 - 48 because of half hours.

Comment: Yes, you can have that also. So, in that case array size will become `24*60`(24 hours X 60 minutes). The core logic will remain same. There will be slight modification to calculate `i` properly in the loop

Comment: for a finer graining, you need larger arrays.